# how to use Akka http web-sockets

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream, akka-http

i have started using  [akka client websockets](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/client-side/websocket-support.html)
i have a question regrading multiple request and response as here the document says

> Note
> The Flow that is returned by this method can only be materialized once. For each request a new flow must be acquired by calling the method again

and here is the [sample code](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/client-side/websocket-support.html#websocketclientflow) this example is for sending a message and printing any incoming message:
so i have a question if i have following scenario

```
request 1 
{
        "janus" : "create",
        "transaction" : "123"
}
response #1 
{
   "janus": "success",
   "transaction": "123",
   "data": {
        "id": 4574061985075210
   }
}
```

and

```
request # 02 {
 "janus": "attach","session_id":${sessionId},"plugin":"janus.plugin.echotest","transaction":"asqeasd4as3d4asdasddas"     
}

response # 02 {
}
----
```

i need to instantiate request #2 based on response #1 so will the following code would be assumed correct ? i have a doubt becuase i am again opening web-sockets connection and according to my knowledge web-sockets connection is opened once and we send and receive messages over that connection but akka web-sockets documents does not support that (at least that is what i understood so far i maybe wrong that's why i am here )

here is my code

```
val source =
      """{ "janus": "create", "transaction":"d1403sa54a5s3d4as3das"}"""
    val jsonAst = source.parseJson

val responseSession: Sink[Message, Future[Done]] =
      Sink.foreach[Message] {
        case message: TextMessage.Strict =>
          println("message response " + message.text)

          val strJson = message.text
          val jsonResponse = strJson.parseJson
          val jsonObj = jsonResponse.asJsObject
          val janus = jsonObj.fields("janus").convertTo[String]
          val data = jsonObj.fields("data").asJsObject
          val sessionIDInt = sessionID.convertTo[BigInt]
          getPluginData(sessionIDInt)//here i am repeating the code of webSocketClientFlow https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/client-side/websocket-support.html#websocketclientflow
//is this the above approach is correct?

          } 


val flow: Flow[Message, Message, Promise[Option[Message]]] =
      Flow.fromSinkAndSourceMat(
        responseSession,
        Source.single(TextMessage(jsonAst.toString())).concatMat(Source.maybe[Message])(Keep.right))(Keep.right)

val (upgradeResponse, closed) =
      Http().singleWebSocketRequest(WebSocketRequest(url, Nil, Option("janus-protocol")), flow)


def getPluginData(sessionId: BigInt): Unit = {
    val responsePlugin: Sink[Message, Future[Done]] =
      Sink.foreach[Message] {
        case message: TextMessage.Strict =>
          println("plugin response " + message.text)

          val strJson = message.text
          val jsonResponse = strJson.parseJson
          val jsonObj = jsonResponse.asJsObject
          val janus = jsonObj.fields("janus").convertTo[String]
          val sessionID = jsonObj.fields("session_id") .convertTo[BigInt]

         
          val data = jsonObj.fields("data").asJsObject
          val handelID = data.fields("id")
          val handleIdInt = handelID.convertTo[BigInt]

          //here i will call another method which has its own sink and source and the same code again ->getHandleDetails(sessionID,handleIdInt)
      }

    val requestPluginJson = s"""{ "janus": "attach","session_id":${sessionId},"plugin":"janus.plugin.echotest","transaction":"asqeasd4as3d4asdasddas"}"""

    val jsonAstPlugin = requestPluginJson.parseJson // or JsonParser(source)

    val requestPlugin = Source.single(TextMessage(jsonAstPlugin.toString()))

    val webSocketFlow = Http().webSocketClientFlow(WebSocketRequest(url, Nil, Option("janus-protocol")))

    val (upgradeResponse, closed) =
      requestPlugin
        .viaMat(webSocketFlow)(Keep.right) // keep the materialized Future[WebSocketUpgradeResponse]
        .toMat(responsePlugin)(Keep.both) // also keep the Future[Done]
        .run()

    val connected = upgradeResponse.flatMap { upgrade =>
      if (upgrade.response.status == StatusCodes.SwitchingProtocols) {
        Future.successful(Done)
      } else {
        throw new RuntimeException(s"Connection failed: ${upgrade.response.status}")
      }
    }

    connected.onComplete(println)
    closed.foreach(_ => println("closed plugin"))

   
  
  }
```